# 2d array minus 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In python numpy:

```
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
b = [2,3,5]
```

want `[1,2,3] -2, [4,5,6]-3, [7,8,9] -5`

e.g. ideal result:

```
[[-1,0,1],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

any way solve this without loop?

Comment: Where are you using numpy? These are all just python lists.

Answer (score 3):

You have not used Numpy at all. It is pretty easy with that. You need to add an extra dimension to b with None or numpy.newaxis and then subtract.

```
import numpy
A = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = numpy.array([2,3,5])

c= A-b[:,None]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[-1  0  1]
 [ 1  2  3]
 [ 2  3  4]]
```

Comment: this doesn't use loops unlike the other answers

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    cur_arr = A[i]
    for j in range(0, len(cur_arr)):
        cur_arr[j] = cur_arr[j] - B[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure python you are going to need a for loop somewhere.

```py
A_L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
B_L = [2,3,5]

sub = lambda a, b : [[x - B for x in A] for A, B in zip(a,b)]

c = sub(A_L,B_L)
print(c)
```

Outputs:
`[[-1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]`